# what is the difference between these 2 for loop in dart?

Tags: flutter, loops, dart, for-loop

i just started learning dart but there is something i cant figure out.
the first loop it prints me from 1 3 5 7 9
the second one it prints for me from 0 to 9.
why did it remove the even numbers from the loop below? i only added a variable in the first loop

```
    void main () {

    for(double a = 0; a <10 ; a++)
    {
      double b = a++;
    
      print (a);
    }
    print("---");
    for(double a = 0; a <10 ; a++)
    {
      print(a);
    }
    }
```

Comment: `a++` increments the value of `a` by `1`. In the first loop you are incrementing `a` twice per iteration, and in the second loop, you increment `a` only once per iteration.

Comment: You added a side-effect. If you wrote `var b = a;` you'd get the result you expect, but instead you wrote `var b = a++;`. This assigns `a` to `b` but then post-increments `a`. So, in the first loop, a is 0, b gets 0, but then a is incremented to 1. Back to the top of the `for` it gets incremented again to 2, etc.

Comment: so in every loop a changes its value according to b?

Answer (score 1):

the `a++` is a shortcut to `a = a +1`, which means that b in each step is getting the value of `a+1` and the second loop would only print odd numbers since you are jumping 2 steps in each loop (a++ in the loop brackets and the b = a++)